# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftDispatch.dylib

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, xcode9

I started to use XCode 9.2 (13772) a day ago and I was walking through some basic tutorials, when it crashed with the message:

```
  Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftDispatch.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
  Reason: image not found
```

Later I discovered that some other applications started to crash with the same message when I tried to open them. I reinstalled all those applications, including XCode, and it helped for all of them, but XCode.
It still crashes the same way.

Does anybody have any ideas how to fix this? I would try to use AppCode, but it still relies on XCode and thus can't work until this issue is resolved.

Here's detailed stack from Apple's crash report:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftDispatch.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
       0x1093db000 -        0x1093dcff7  com.apple.dt.Xcode (9.2 - 13772) <99E158D7-ADB3-3CD8-9762-716A74599C12> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
       0x1093e7000 -        0x10999dfff  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation (9.2 - 13763) <78811324-8E42-36B8-81E3-74A1D4AC5F7E> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation
       0x109c08000 -        0x109f85ff7  com.apple.dt.DVTKit (9.2 - 13763) <76F3AD2F-A605-3FC3-BF66-E09B2B991852> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
       0x10a1df000 -        0x10a94efff  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation (9.2 - 13772) <CC7015F9-971F-3C05-A3E9-2A20694D028B> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/Versions/A/IDEFoundation
       0x10ae83000 -        0x10b842fff  com.apple.dt.IDEKit (9.2 - 13772) <C19A9742-1C5E-345D-B0A5-E2CB0D88EA39> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit
       0x10bf9b000 -        0x10bfa9fff +libswiftAVFoundation.dylib (4.0.3 - 900.0.74.1) <FC937BB3-D0FB-35D1-9270-FA2DC117821B> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
       0x10bfb9000 -        0x10c37cfff +libswiftCore.dylib (4.0.3 - 900.0.74.1) <CE685663-7897-3330-83B6-74EEFE1A116F> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
       0x10c6b4000 -        0x10c6bbff7 +libswiftCoreAudio.dylib (4.0.3 - 900.0.74.1) <68E5B93C-487C-31C1-AC5D-4BFDCCF4B903> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib
       0x10c6ca000 -        0x10c6cdff7 +libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib (4.0.3 - 900.0.74.1) <51C48082-D5E2-34FD-9E5E-E5B822A3A1D4> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
       0x10c6d6000 -        0x10c6e6ff7 +libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib (4.0.3 - 900.0.74.1) <6EE1A751-4A73-3BFD-B683-6F232E2CA3BC> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
       0x10c6ff000 -        0x10c704ffe +libswiftCoreImage.dylib (4.0.3 - 900.0.74.1) <CBA31255-A204-3F42-87F9-DC54338B97F0> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
       0x10c70b000 -        0x10c715ff7 +libswiftCoreMedia.dylib (4.0.3 - 900.0.74.1) <6441DF57-06CB-3AFF-B52E-8CC230D11D97> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib
       0x10c71d000 -        0x10c723fff +libswiftDarwin.dylib (4.0.3 - 900.0.74.1) <0C6938A7-E862-3D6C-A235-0C9293F73141> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
       0x11563d000 -        0x11568798f  dyld (519.2.2) <6695F30B-4E88-3C0B-9867-7D738C44A3E6> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff3a388000 -     0x7fff3b1e5fff  com.apple.AppKit (6.9 - 1561.20.106) <D03AE413-C601-3B7C-A3D4-FC32F4C13940> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7fff3c5c8000 -     0x7fff3c5c8fff  com.apple.Cocoa (6.11 - 22) <1553F279-3C7B-3A48-87E6-35237F7F452E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
    0x7fff3cd62000 -     0x7fff3d202fe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1451) <7AFE9C8F-A562-3AFC-8402-117AA02F57E9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff3ee98000 -     0x7fff3f25dfff  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1451) <B99F94E7-117E-39CC-A65D-B7AEA8998481> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff624f9000 -     0x7fff624faff3  libSystem.B.dylib (1252) <47329E26-DC23-3EBA-9461-37755368327D> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff63afa000 -     0x7fff63ee87e7  libobjc.A.dylib (723) <93A92316-DE1E-378C-8891-99720B50D075> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am using AVG Free for Mac. Yesterday it removed libswiftDispatch.dylib to quarantine because of 'MacOS:BitCoinMiner-AS'. This seems like a false positive, see:
https://discussions.agilebits.com/discussion/86860/avg-quarantined-1password-libswiftdispatch-dylib/p2
https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=216164.msg1449648#msg1449648 (AVG and Avast are the same company)

So for me the fix was restoring this file from quarantine.

Comment: Yes, you were right! Avast is a requirement on my working laptop, and it put this library (all its copies, actually) to quarantine without any alerts :) Thanks!

Comment: my avg cannot run, too. can I restore the files manually? Where is quarantine folder is located?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using `Swift` code in `Objective-C` project, right?
If so please be aware that:

> "If you are building an app that does not use Swift but embeds content such as a framework that does, Xcode will not include these libraries in your app."

[Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1881/_index.html)

To fix your problem try the following steps:

- go to your app target's `Build Settings` in `Xcode`
- find `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` setting
- set it from `NO` (which is default for `Obj-C` projects) to `YES`

After it clean the project (Shift+Cmd+K) and then build (Cmd+B) it again.

Comment: Evgeny, I didn't change these settings indeed, but the thing is that I can't even open XCode, it crashes immediately...

Comment: I had to turn this flag on in one of the frameworks I was using, and it worked.

Comment: Just (Shift+Cmd+K) and (Cmd+B). Worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered the same problem. This occurred following the install of the High Sierra Supplemental update 10.13.3 supplemental.    The same library appears to be referenced by git, so git on my machine is failing.

Comment: I am having the same problem. The problem just ocurred following the install of the High Sierra update 10.13.3. Reading other comments I just found that my Avast put this library to quarantine, and that is a false positive from Avast and AVG. Restoring that file from quarantine solved my problem.

Comment: @Chinokao my avg cannot run, too. can I restore the files manually? Where is quarantine folder is located?

Comment: @malhobayyeb Sorry, I'm using Avast, not AVG. I guess you need to go to de quarantine, select the file with right button and push something like "restore file from quarantine" or something like. If you can't run AVG, maybe you can find where is quarantine folder located with a little research in Google. Hope it helped.